# How to add an endpoint to WP

Tags: rest-api

I am wondering how can I add an endpoint where I would return the ninja form plugin data. I have made a function where I am getting the data from the ninja form:

```
add_action('init', function() {

function getNinjaFormData(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $id = $request->get_param('id');
    $settings = ['label', 'type', 'required'];
    $formFields = Ninja_Forms()->form(1)->get_fields();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($formFields as $formField) {
      $key = $formField->get_setting('key');
      foreach ($settings as $setting) {
        $data[$key][] = $formField->get_setting($setting);
      }
    }

    return $data;
  }
});

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'ninja-forms/', '/id/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'getNinjaFormData',
  ));
});
```

But, this is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When asking for help, in general you should clarify "not working" by including the output of your existing code and explaining how it differs from what you expect. In this case I'm pretty sure I know the problem, but I have to guess because you haven't actually stated it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a WP_REST_Response object instead of an array.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_response/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a WP_REST_Response object. Edit your code like the following:

```
add_action('init', function() {

function getNinjaFormData(WP_REST_Request $request) {
    $id = $request->get_param('id');
    $settings = ['label', 'type', 'required'];
    $formFields = Ninja_Forms()->form(1)->get_fields();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($formFields as $formField) {
      $key = $formField->get_setting('key');
      foreach ($settings as $setting) {
        $data[$key][] = $formField->get_setting($setting);
      }
    }

    return new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );
  }
});

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'ninja-forms/', '/id/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'getNinjaFormData',
  ));
});
```